# Why does my while loop not work?

Tags: java, loops, logfile

basically its a logfile reader function using other logreader class and its functions like 
readLine() and hasMoreLines() I dont know why my while loop is not working properly
as it is supossed to output the all tokens which i made  using tokenizer

```
public void readLogFile() throws Exception {

    LogReader lr = new LogReader();
    LogEntry [] arr = new LogEntry[700];
    String logLine;
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("OUTSIDE WHILE LOOP"); // for testing

        logLine = lr.fileReader.nextLine(); // objct log reader
        System.out.println("A DAM LINE IN OUTER LOOP"); // for testing
        while (lr.hasMoreLines()) {
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(lr.readLine());
            String date = token.nextToken();
            String time = token.nextToken();
            String siteName = token.nextToken();
            String computerName = token.nextToken();
            String sIpAddress = token.nextToken();
            String csMethod = token.nextToken();
            String csUriStem = token.nextToken();
            String csUriQuery = token.nextToken();
            String sPort = token.nextToken();
            String csUsername = token.nextToken();
            String csIpAddress = token.nextToken();
            String csVersion = token.nextToken();
            String csUserAgent = token.nextToken();
            String csCookie = token.nextToken();
            String csReferer = token.nextToken();
            String csHost = token.nextToken();
            String scStatus = token.nextToken();
            String scSubStatus = token.nextToken();
            String scWin32Status = token.nextToken();
            String scBytes = token.nextToken();
            String csBytes = token.nextToken();
            String timeTaken = token.nextToken();
```

//BASICALLY ITS NOT EXECUTING THIS PART BELOW

```
            LogEntry le = new LogEntry(date, time, siteName, computerName,
                    csMethod, sIpAddress, csUriStem, csUriQuery, sPort,
                    csUsername, csIpAddress, csVersion, csUserAgent,
                    csCookie, csReferer, csHost, scStatus, scSubStatus,
                    scWin32Status, scBytes, csBytes, timeTaken);
            arr[count++]=le;
            System.out.println(le.toString());
            System.out.println("A DAM LINE IN WHILE LOOP"); // for testing
        }
```

Comment: Not working means what? `incorrect output`, `error or exceptions`? what? If its `incorrect output` then what is coming and what is expected? If its `error or exception`, post those relevant details.

Comment: incorrect output , just displaying output lines before while loop need to output the logfile associated to string method

Comment: If its `incorrect output` then post what is coming and what is expected? You can update your question.

Answer (score 0):

lr is just initialised. I dont see any assigments to it, this the control is not entering the  while loop